# looking for a user interface to pick time ranges

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need a user interface for my website which allows users to pick up a time slot(eg: 6-8hrs) between 1-24hrs range. Some time ranges will not be allowed to pick as they might be reserved (eg: 7-9hrs).So user can only be allowed to pick from available time ranges.I thought jquery slider would be great but i could'nt find any way to block some ranges in between the slider range.Is there any easy way to achive what i'm looking for?

thanks,
ravi

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I believe that the most user-friendly way to do this would be to actually show a calendar-style view to users and use colours to indicate whether a specific time period is available or not.

Allow a user to click on a time slot to specify the starting time, and if you need the user to customise the duration of this meeting/appointment, follow up by asking them to specify a duration using a combo box.